# Change standard quantity on product page from 0 to 1 (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, products, product-view, quantity, product-page

When a customer visits a product page, the order quantity is standard set to 0.
I want it to be automatically set to 1, but I have no clue how to do this. How do you do this?

[image: [1]]

<sub>Translation: *Normale prijs* = Normal price; *Aantal* = Amount/Quantity; *Aan winkelwagen toevoegen* = Add to cart</sub>

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about your current issue there?

Comment: What do you mean with current issue? If you mean I forgot to accept the answer: I'm sorry , I've accepted your answer now.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

--<del>The easiest way is that we can change the input value from template: (override this template - **not recommend**)

*vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml*</del>

--The second way is the Magento default config: **STORES > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options > Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart >** > Add **Customer Group** > change to **1**

Comment: Thanks, second way did the trick. (Haven't tried the first way.)

Comment: The second way should be preferred :-)

Comment: I would say the second method is also the easiest, wouldn't even mention the first

Answer (score 5):

Khoa's second option is the preferred one. Anyways, this sometimes does not work for bundles.
There you have to also carefully check the bundles option's and quantities.

The logic for the default quantity could be found in

`\Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option::getDefaultValues`

In my case a required option did not have a default option, leading to a zero default quantity.

Answer (score 5):

> --The second way is the Magento default config: STORES > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options > Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart > > Add Customer Group > change to 1

For some clarity on this question if the above doesn't work:

This was already done on the site I was working on, the issue was that on the individual product (in my case a configurable parent) under **CATALOG** > **Products** > ***PRODUCT*** > **Advanced Inventory** > **Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** was set to NOT use this default config:
[image]

Changing this to Use Config Settings: 
[image]

Changes the default qty to be 1 on the frontend:

[image]