# magento 2 how to set quantity 0 to 1 on listing page (category page)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2

```
<input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       maxlength="12"
                       placeholder="1"
                       value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty form-control"
                       data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
```

I have changed quantity from admin panel 0 to 1 it's working on the product page but it's not working on the category page please check my above code which I have used on the listing page.

[This is one solution I have found but it's not working on category page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136568/change-standard-quantity-on-product-page-from-0-to-1-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

```
     <input type="number"
                   name="qty"
                   id="qty"
                   maxlength="12"
                   placeholder="1"
                   value="<?php echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_product)?$this->getMinimalQty($_product):1) ?>"
                   title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty form-control"
                   data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                   />
```

[now its working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245551/magento-2-how-to-set-product-minimum-quantity-selected-to-minimum-qty-configured) i have changed value code